# Covariance in a function reference

Tags: scala

Say I define the following list and two function references:

```
var list = List[Any => String]()

val f1: Any => String = _.toString
val f2: Int => String = _.toString
```

When I try to add them to the list thus:

```
list :+= f1
list :+= f2
```

My second line won't compile with the following error:

> found   : List[Int => String]
>
> required: List[Any => String]

Is there some way I can define my list to make the Any parameter covariant so I can assign functions other than those with 'Any' parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there some way I can define my list to make the Any parameter covariant so I can assign functions other than those with 'Any' parameters?

There isn't, because the parameter types of a `FunctionN` are *contravariant*. An `Any => A` is near the *bottom* of the type tree. An `Any => String` is an `Int => String`, but not the other way around.

An `Any => String` is a function that can accept *anything* as an argument, and returns a `String`. It knows what to do in all cases, because every type extends `Any`. But an `Int => String` *only* handles `Int` arguments, so there are infinitely many types that it cannot handle as arguments, and casting it to `Any => String` wouldn't make sense. It would fail.

Imagine you change `f2` to be:

```
 val f2: Int => String = i => (i * 2).toString
```

How can you change that to work with `Any`? The answer is you can't.